# Facebook plugin on Squarespace blog

Tags: blogs, squarespace

I added the Facebook plug-in in the post-code injection block, but then every new blog post includes the same “test” comment of mine. Any idea how to correct so that each new blog has a cleared FB comment section?[image]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code, as provided to you by Facebook, does not produce a dynamically changing URL for each new blog post. So, we must set the `data-href` attribute dynamically. The simplest way to do this is to use the following instead of what you're using now:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="" data-width="" data-numposts="5"></div>
<script>
  document.getElementsByClassName("fb-comments")[0].setAttribute("data-href", window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname);
</script>
```

In the code above, we leave the `data-href` attribute empty, and then fill it in using JavaScript immediately following the `div`. The script then inserts the URL of the current page, making the comments unique to that page.

Comment: That worked to clear the comment from new blog posts, but it also cleared the real comment from the prior post. Also, even the comment block is on the blog, no one is able to comment any longer. Unless you have a fix, I will have to go back to the old code. Thanks, though, for weighing in on this issue. Really appreciate your time.

Comment: Okay, I think it's now working. It kept trying to pull up a login box for Facebook when I clicked on the comment box using my MacBook Pro. When I tried to comment on my iPhone, it permitted me to select which Facebook account (personal or business) I wanted to post from. That worked. And now I just tried again on the laptop and it worked. So thank you so much!